# Code on UserControl creating error

Tags: asp.net

I use the following code to open a PDF on my asp .net application:

```
    Response.Buffer = false; //new
    Response.Clear(); //new
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
    Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
    try
    {
        Response.TransmitFile(filename); 
        Response.End();
    }
    catch
    {
        Response.ClearContent();
    }
```

Works fine in most cases, but when I put this code on a UserControl button event it gave me a parser error, is there a simple way to either fix or trigger a complete postback so it should work?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, do this in page_load:

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).RegisterPostBackControl(Button);
```